# How to iterate through rows and setting a row to a sum of columns in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Lets say I have a table1:

```
        id    column2 column3 column4
row1     1    name1   1       1
row2     2    name2   1       1
row3     3    name3   1       1
row4     1    name1   1       1
```

I have another table2:

```
     id name1  name2  name3
row1     
row2    
row3
```

So id in table2 has all the same values in id in table1 except only the unique values.

What I need to do is take the sum of the values under column 3 and 4 of each id and set them to the corresponding name column under table2 which depends on column2 in table1.

So the resulting table2 should look like:

```
        id name1  name2  name3
row1      1  4       0      0
row2      2  0       2      0
row3      3  0       0      2
```

Does anybody have any idea on how to do this? Sorry if my question is horribly worded.
I'm using an Oracle Server.

Comment: What is your actual database? MySQL, SQL Server, and Oracle are all very different beasts.

Comment: I am using an Oracle Server.

Comment: Then don't tag it with MySQL and SQL Server - neither of those is Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, you want to insert the "SUM" in table2?

If so, you could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table2(id, name1, name2, name3) 
SELECT id, 
   SUM(DECODE(column2, 'name1', (column3 + column4), 0)),
   SUM(DECODE(column2, 'name2', (column3 + column4), 0)),
   SUM(DECODE(column2, 'name3', (column3 + column4), 0))
FROM  table1
GROUP BY id;
```